# Population growth problem, when its' growth is 3x increased at the time $t=1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I have no idea how to do this exercise. **The problem:** Population growth rate is proportional to the the amount of population. At the time between $t=0$ and $t=1$ the population has increased three times. After how long will the population be 100 times larger than at $t=0$?

My understanding of it:
$P'-kP=0$

$Pe^{-kt}=C$ where $C$ - any constant.

$P(t)=Ce^{kt}$ This is general solution to the problem.

Then at $t=0$ $P(0)=C\cdot e^0 = C$ but the value at $t=0$ is not given so there is nothing I can do. I know that logarithm is involved in solution, but I don't know why and what are the steps to resolve this problem. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ِAssume that $P(0)=C=a$, and $P(1)=Ce^{k}=3a$, now divide $\frac{P(1)}{P(0)}$

we get: $e^k=3$, so $\boxed{k=\ln(3)}$

We obtained earlier that $P(t)=Ce^{kt}$, this means that $P(t)=ae^{t\ln(3)}$

Replacing $P(t)$ by $100a$ [this is the required population], we get:

$100a=ae^{t\ln(3)}$, dividing by $a$ we get: $100=e^{t\ln(3)}$, taking the natural logarithm on both sides we get: $\ln(100)=t\ln(3)$, dividing both sides by $\ln(3)$ to get the required time, $t=\frac{\ln(100)}{\ln(3)}\approx 4.1918...$

Comment: Why do you divide P(1) with P(0), does it represent the population growth rate?

Comment: It does not represent the population growth rate, but we divide to cancel the $C$. We are having two equations, the first is $C=a$, and the second is $Ce^k=3a$, how can we solve for $C$ and $k$? See when dividing the two equations the $C$ cancels, and we get $e^k=3$. (So it is only to solve the equation for $C$ and $k$). Hope this helps.

Comment: @user You can email me at hussainhrq2@gmail.com , I have over 25 very good examples with good explanation. I can share with you if you wish.

Comment: Would it be a mistake if I didn't notate the amount as $a$ and just left it as $C$?